# Google charts - How to remove annotation from the bars?

Tags: charts, bar-chart, google-visualization

I really do not know, what to call this? annotation or legend? both are different from this, I think. Take a look at the picture

[image: bar graph]

I have found and tried various ways to remove annotation/legend like

```
 legend: {position: 'none'}
```

but, no success. Please help me to resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in google charts, those are annotations, and are added to the chart,
by adding columns to the data table, using an `'annotation'` [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available).

to remove, remove the columns from the data table.
see following snippet...

before...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'x');
data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});  // <-- remove
data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});  // <-- remove
data.addColumn('number', 'y2');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});  // <-- remove
data.addRow(['a', 1, '1', 1, '1', 1, '1']);  // <-- remove string values for above columns
```

after...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'x');
data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
data.addColumn('number', 'y2');
data.addRow(['a', 1, 1, 1]);
```

---

annotations can also be added using a calculated column in a `DataView`.
see following snippet...

before...

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1,
                 { calc: "stringify",    // <-- remove calculated column
                   sourceColumn: 1,
                   type: "string",
                   role: "annotation" },
                 2]);
```

after...

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, 2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help + my common sense. ;)